# Firebase Cloud Messaging testing themes from the Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending notifications to my android app over firebase cloud messaging, which works fine. I test this by sending a test message to my device from the firebase Console.
Now I want to send messages only to devices that subscribed to specific topics. The problem is that the notification always pops up, no matter what theme I have defined, even if I did not subscribe to it. Any ideas why this happens?

I do not use any custom logic in my app, I just integrated the firebase SDKs.

build.gradle

```
dependencies{
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
onCreate(){
...
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test");
}
```

[image]

Comment: please share your implementation on the app side.

Comment: Please see updated answer

Comment: I didn't mean the gradle. I meant the implementation of the onReceive() function and everything. the code.

Comment: Updated. This is all I do.